# Counting two to one functions

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

> Let f be a function. We say that f is two-to-one provided for each $b \in\operatorname{im} f$ there are exactly two elements $a_1, a_2 \in\operatorname{dom} f$ s.t. $f(a_1) = f(a_2) = b$.
>   For a positive integer $n$, let $A$ be a $2n$-element set and $B$ be an $n$-element set. How many functions $f: A\to B$ are two-to-one?

I am having trouble with the issue of how to count the number of functions that would be two to one and I was hoping I could get some help.

Here is my approach:

We know that $|A| = 2n$ and $|B| = n$.  So we can generalize this by saying:
$A$ = {1,2,...n,...2n} and $B$ = {1,2,...n}.
Any function $f: A \rightarrow B$ will look like:
f = { (?,1), (?,1), ...(?,n), (?,n) }.

Since we must cover every element of $A$, we have $\binom{2n}{2}$ choices for every $n$ elements of $b$ so there are $n^{\binom{2n}{2}}$ functions.

Could someone please explain to me why this logic is either correct or incorrect?  I am quite lost on how to deal with this.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have ${2n\choose 2}$ ways of picking two elements that get mapped to $1$ in $B$.  We have ${2n-2\choose 2}$ ways of picking two other elements that get mapped to $2$ in $B$.  And so on, giving an answer of $${2n\choose 2}{2n-2\choose 2}\cdots {2\choose 2}=\frac{2n(2n-1)}{2!}\frac{(2n-2)(2n-3)}{2!}\cdots \frac{(2)(1)}{2!}=\frac{(2n)!}{2^n}$$

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but why is the final coefficient 2 choose 2?  I appreciate the help!

Comment: Because at the very end there are two elements of $A$ that haven't yet been assigned; they both need to go to $n$, in $B$.